# How to write join query for two JObjects in mvc c#?

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

This is my code.

```
var students={data:[{"name":"abc","id":"101","dept_id":"213"},{"name":"abc","id":"101","dept_id":"212"}]};
var departments={data:[{"name":"it","id":"212"},{"name":"csc","id":"213"}]}
```

I have two JObjects like `students` and `departments` . In students array contains `dept_id` key value based on that add `dept_name` key with value from `departments` array.
I want to get Output like:-

```
var students={data:[{"name":"abc","id":"101","dept_id":"213","dept_name":"csc"},{"name":"abc","id":"101","dept_id":"212","dept_name":"it"}]};
```

Answer (score 0):

1: Use JArray in stead of JObject:

```
var students = JArray.Parse("[{ \"name\":\"abc\",\"id\":\"101\",\"dept_id\":\"213\"},{ \"name\":\"abc\",\"id\":\"101\",\"dept_id\":\"212\"}]");
var departments = JArray.Parse("[{ \"name\":\"it\",\"id\":\"212\"},{ \"name\":\"csc\",\"id\":\"213\"}]");
```

2. Join:

```
// Method syntax
var joined = students.Join(departments, s => s["dept_id"].Value<string>(), 
                                        d => d["id"].Value<string>(), 
                                        (s, d) => new { name = s["name"].Value<string>(),
                                                        id = s["id"].Value<string>(),
                                                        dept_id = s["dept_id"].Value<string>(),
                                                        dept_name = d["dept_name"].Value<string>() });
```

**Edit:** In case you have multiple students per dept. or multiple depts. per student (or both), use **.GroupJoin** in stead of **.Join.**

Comment: for suppose 20 keys are exists in students

Comment: @sivakishore See my edit - this will work for any number of students, but if you have a many-to-many relationship, use GroupJoin in stead of Join.